# Can't login in yii with pgsql

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, authentication

I'm new in yii framework. I wanna make simple login page. I'm using pgsql for this. I have input the values to table in database. When I try login, it's not redirect to homepage but to blank page. This is my link: http://mahasiswa.cs.ui.ac.id/~nabila.clydea/tugasakhir/index.php?r=site/login.

This is my table:

> create table users(
>       id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
>       username varchar(100),
>       email varchar(100),
>       password varchar(100),
>       level integer
>       );
>
> insert into users(username,email,password,level)
>   VALUES('nabila','nabila.clydea@ui.ac.id','halo123',1);

and this is my User.php in protected/models

> 

```
 /**
 * This is the model class for table "1306464133.users".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table '1306464133.users':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property integer $level
 */
 class User extends CActiveRecord
 {
/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return '1306464133.users';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('level', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('username, email, password', 'length', 'max'=>100),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, username, email, password, level', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'username' => 'Username',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'level' => 'Level',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 *
 * Typical usecase:
 * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
 * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
 * models according to data in model fields.
 * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
 *
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
 * based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('username',$this->username,true);
    $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
    $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
    $criteria->compare('level',$this->level);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return User the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
}
```

and my UserIdentity.php

```
/**
* UserIdentity represents the data needed to identity a user.
* It contains the authentication method that checks if the provided
* data can identity the user.
*/
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
/**
 * Authenticates a user.
 * The example implementation makes sure if the username and password
 * are both 'demo'.
 * In practical applications, this should be changed to authenticate
 * against some persistent user identity storage (e.g. database).
 * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
 */
public function authenticate()
{
    $user=User::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?',array($this->username));

    if($user === null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    elseif($user->password !== $this->password)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

and the UserController look like this:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
 * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
 */
public $layout='//layouts/column2';

/**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
    );
}

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a particular model.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
 */
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}

/**
 * Creates a new model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new User;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Updates a particular model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Deletes a particular model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
 */
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
    if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
}

/**
 * Lists all models.
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

/**
 * Manages all models.
 */
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new User('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['User']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['User'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
 * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
 * @return User the loaded model
 * @throws CHttpException
 */
public function loadModel($id)
{
    $model=User::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}

/**
 * Performs the AJAX validation.
 * @param User $model the model to be validated
 */
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='user-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
}
```

my SiteController

```
<?php

class SiteController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Declares class-based actions.
 */
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
        ),
        // page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
        // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
        'page'=>array(
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * This is the default 'index' action that is invoked
 * when an action is not explicitly requested by users.
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    $this->render('index');
}

/**
 * This is the action to handle external exceptions.
 */
public function actionError()
{
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            echo $error['message'];
        else
            $this->render('error', $error);
    }
}

/**
 * Displays the contact page
 */
public function actionContact()
{
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->name).'?=';
            $subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->subject).'?=';
            $headers="From: $name <{$model->email}>\r\n".
                "Reply-To: {$model->email}\r\n".
                "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";

            mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$subject,$model->body,$headers);
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to  you as soon as possible.');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
}

/**
 * Displays the login page
 */
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}

/**
 * Logs out the current user and redirect to homepage.
 */
public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::app()->user->logout();
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
}
}
```

login.php in views/site/login.php

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */
/* @var $model LoginForm */
/* @var $form CActiveForm  */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Login';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
'Login',
);
?>

<h1>Login</h1>

<p>Please fill out the following form with your login credentials:</p>

<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
),
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>

</div>

<div class="row rememberMe">
    <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->label($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

this is protected/views/site/index.php

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.reliablecounter.com" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.reliablecounter.com/count.php?   page=mahasiswa.cs.ui.ac.id/~nabila.clydea/web/index.php?r=site/index&digit=style/plain/1/&reloads=0" 
alt="" title="" border="0"></a><br />
<a href="http://www.fabberforum.com" target="_blank" 
style="font-family: Geneva, Arial; font-size: 9px; color: #330010; text-decoration: none;">3d  printing forum</a>
```

Comment: Login action is a part of site controller, but instead, you wrote your UserController here. Please update your question with `SiteController` and its `Login` action

Comment: What is in the file `protected/views/site/index.php`?

Comment: I have add protected views/site/index.php